Update Dynamic Form Using JSON Laravel
I tried a dynamic form with json_encode data and an upload image field. When I try to update the old data, create new data, or delete data, the image field is always overwritten with the latest file name, so the other old image does not appear.
View
@php
  $size = json_decode($packs->size, true);
  $barcode = json_decode($packs->barcode, true);
@endphp

@foreach($size as $key => $pack)
    <label class="control-label">Size <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pack Size" class="form-control form-control-modern" value="{{$pack}}" name="size[]" />
     <label class="control-label">Barcode <span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-modern" placeholder="Barcode" name="barcode[]" value="{{$barcode[$key]}}" />
     
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="product-size-remove text-color-danger float-end">Remove</a>
     <label class="control-label">Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="image[]" />
 @endforeach
 
 <a href="#" class="product-size-add-new btn btn-primary btn-px-4 btn-py-2">+ Add New</a>

Controller
if ($request->size !== "" && $request->barcode !== "" && $request->image == "") {

        $product_id = json_encode($products->id);
        $size = json_encode($request->size);
        $barcode = json_encode($request->barcode);
        $size_updated_by = json_encode(Auth::user()->id);

        $packdata = [];
        $packdata['product_id'] = $product_id;
        $packdata['size'] = $size;
        $packdata['barcode'] = $barcode;
        $packdata['updated_by'] = $size_updated_by;

        $packs = ProductSize::where('product_id', $id)->first();
        $packs->update($packdata);
    } else {
        //upload pack image
        $fileNames = [];
        foreach ($request->file('image') as $pack_image) {
            $fileName = $pack_image->hashName();
            $pack_image->storeAs('products', $fileName);
            $fileNames[] = $fileName;
        }

        //submit product pack with image
        $product_id = json_encode($products->id);
        $size = json_encode($request->size);
        $barcode = json_encode($request->barcode);
        $image = json_encode($fileNames);
        $size_updated_by = json_encode(Auth::user()->id);

        $packdata = [];
        $packdata['product_id'] = $product_id;
        $packdata['size'] = $size;
        $packdata['barcode'] = $barcode;
        $packdata['image'] = $image;
        $packdata['updated_by'] = $size_updated_by;

        $packs = ProductSize::where('product_id', $id)->first();
        $packs->update($packdata);
    }

Please help because I'm still a beginner. Thank you
